# simplify the usetikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf

For some reasons I use the packets below.

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,chains,quotes,positioning,shapes.geometric}
```

I believe that some of the are doubled, but I don't know what I can delete, because the document is too large to find the results.

Comment: you call `calc` 3 times, `shapes` 2 times, `positionning` twice.

Comment: I usually alphabetical  order `tikz` libraries in one `\usetikzlibraries`. With this I can be simply avoid to load some libraries twice or more times ...

Comment: @AndréC , thanks for your answer! **1)** Should I delete 2 of 3 `calc`? **2)** Is it the same `shapes`, `shapes.symbols`, `shapes.callouts` and `shapes.geometric`?

Comment: @Zarko , thanks for your answer! The problem is that I don't know really what I cave to keep and what I should delete.

Comment: If you have two or more of the same, you can definitely delete all except one. Otherwise, I think you have to go through all diagrams, look at the code and figure out which libraries are required, or comment out one library at the time, compile your document, and look for errors.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , thanks for your answer! That's difficult... The document is 350 pages splitted to 20 files.

Comment: The first option is perhaps a bit difficult, as it requires you to know the various libraries well. The second option (delete library, compile, repeat) isn't difficult, just time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you call the libraries does not matter. If you call it twice, it doesn't matter.
As for me, I will call them by their theme such as this:

As user121799 just pointed out in his commentary, the `shapes` library loads the libraries `shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric,` then it's useless to load them twice.

```
% shapes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%arrows
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
%decorations
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns,shadows.blur,fadings}
% miscellaneous
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,positioning,fpu,angles,fit,spy,chains}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do on this way. What has common `chains` and `fpu` for example?  The OP should be only a little bit more pedantic ...

Comment: the last line is a mixture in my opinion unclassifiable

Comment: -1 because the `shapes` library loads `shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric`.

Comment: @user121799 I just checked and you're right. I correct my answer.